# How does compiler figure out fixed point of a functor and how cata work at leaf level?

Tags: haskell, category-theory, recursion-schemes, fixpoint-combinators, catamorphism

I feel like understanding the abstract concept of fixed point of a functor, however, I am still struggling to figure out the exact implementation of it and its catamorphism in Haskell.

For example, if I define, as according to the book of "Category Theory for Programers" -- page 359, the following algebra

```
-- (Int, LiftF e Int -> Int)

data ListF e a = NilF | ConsF e a

lenAlg :: ListF e Int -> Int
lenAlg (ConsF e n) -> n + 1
lenAlg NilF = 0
```

by definition of catamorphism, the following function could be applied to ListF's fixed point, which is a List, to calculate its length.

```
cata lenAlg :: [e] -> Int
cata lenAlg = lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) . unFix
```

I have two confusions. First, how does Haskell compiler know that List is **THE** fixed point of ListF? I know conceptually it is, but how does the compiler know, i.e., what if we define another List' that is everything the same as List, I bet compiler does not automatically infer that List' is the fixed point of ListF too, or does it? (I'd be amazed).

Second, due to the recursive nature of cata lenAlg, it always tries to unFix the outer layer of data constructor to expose the inner layer of functor (is this interpretation of mine even correct by the way?). But, what if we are already at the leaf, how could we invoke this function call?

```
fmap (cata lenAlg) Nil
```

As an example, could someone help write an execution trace for the below function call to clarify?

```
cata lenAlg Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)
```

I am probably missing something that is obvious, however I hope this question still makes sense for other people that share similar confusions.

---

answer summary

---

@n.m. answered my first question by pointing out that in order for Haskell compiler to figure out Functor A is a fixed point of Functor B, we need to be explicit. In this case, it is

```
type List e = Fix (ListF e)
```

@luqui and @Will Ness pointed out that calling fmap (cata lenAlg) on the leaf, which is NilF in this case, will return NilF back, because of the definition of fmap.

```
-- f :: a -> b
fmap f (ConsF e a) = ConsF e (f b)
fmap f NilF        = NilF
```

I'd accept @n.m.'s answer as it directly addressed my first (bigger) question, but I do like all three answers. Thanks a lot for all your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"List is the fixed point of ListF" is a fast-and-loose figure of speech. While [fast and loose reasoning is morally correct](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/~nad/publications/danielsson-et-al-popl2006.html), you always need to keep in mind the boring correct thing. Which is as follows:

*any least fixpoint of `ListF e` is isomorphic to `[e]`*.

Now "the compiler" (that's a fast-and-loose word for "the Haskell language" by the way) is not aware of isomorphisms of this kind. You can write isomorphic types all day

```
data []    x = []   | (:)   x ([]    x)    -- the imaginary built-in definition of []
data ListA x = NilA | ConsA x (ListA x)
data ListB x = NilB | ConsB x (ListB x)
data ListC x = NilC | ConsC x (ListC x)
```

and the compiler will never treat them as "the same type". Nor will it know that the fixpoint of `ListF e` is the same as `[e]`, or indeed what a fixpoint is. If you want to use these isomorphisms,  you need to teach the compiler about them by writing some code (e.g. by defining instances of `Data.Types.Isomorphic`), and then specifying the isomorphism explicitly each time you want to use it!

Having this is mind, let's look at `cata` you have defined. The first thing that mets the eye is that the attempt at defining the type signature is a syntax error. Let's remove it and just define the function in GHCi (I changed the name of the parameter to `f` to avoid confusion, and fixed a few typos in the definition of ListF)

```
Main> data ListF e a = NilF | ConsF e a
Main> let lenAlg :: ListF e Int -> Int
Main|     lenAlg (ConsF e n) = n + 1
Main|     lenAlg NilF = 0
Main|
Main>
Main> :m + Data.Fix
Main Data.Fix> cata f = f . fmap (cata f) . unFix
Main Data.Fix> :t cata
cata :: Functor f => (f b -> b) -> Fix f -> b
Main Data.Fix> :t cata lenAlg
cata lenAlg :: Functor (ListF e) => Fix (ListF e) -> Int
```

This says that in order to use `lenAlg`, you need to:

- define an instance of `Functor` for `ListF e`
- use `Fix (ListF e)` (which is **a** fixpoint of ListF) explicitly. Wishing "the fixpoint of ListF" into existence just doesn't work. There's no magic.

So let's do this:

```
Main Data.Fix> instance Functor (ListF e) where
Main Data.Fix|     fmap f NilF = NilF
Main Data.Fix|     fmap f (ConsF e a) = ConsF e (f a)
Main Data.Fix>
Main Data.Fix> :t cata lenAlg
cata lenAlg :: Fix (ListF e) -> Int
```

Great, now we can calculate the length of a ListF-based Fix-wrapped list. But let's define a few helper definitions first.

```
Main Data.Fix> type List e = Fix (ListF e)
Main Data.Fix> nil = Fix (NilF)
Main Data.Fix> let infixr 7 ~~                   -- using an infix operator for cons
Main Data.Fix|     h ~~ t = Fix (ConsF h t)
Main Data.Fix|
Main Data.Fix>
Main Data.Fix> myList = (1::Int) ~~ 2 ~~ 3 ~~ 4 ~~ nil
Main Data.Fix> :t myList
myList :: Fix (ListF Int)
```

Here's our "list" (a member of a type that is isomorphic to `[Int]` to be precise). Let's `cata lenAlg` it:

```
Main Data.Fix> cata lenAlg myList
4
```

Success!

Bottom line: the compiler knows nothing,you need to explain it everything.

Answer (score 5):

The only way the compiler can know about the relationship between `ListF e` and `[e]` is if you tell it.  You haven't provided enough context to answer exactly how, but I can infer that `unFix` has type

```
unFix :: [e] -> ListF e [e]
```

that is, it unrolls the top layer.  `unFix` may be more general, for example in [`recursion-schemes`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.3/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) a type family is used to associate data types with their underlying functors.  But this is where the two types are connected.

---

As for your second question, you need to be clearer about when you have a list and when you have a `ListF`.  They are completely different.

```
fmap (cata lenAlg) Nil
```

Here the functor you are mapping over is `ListF e` for whatever `e` you like.   That is, it's this `fmap`:

```
fmap :: (a -> b) -> ListF e a -> ListF e b
```

If you implement `instance Functor (ListF e)` yourself (always a good exercise) and get it to compile, you will find that `Nil` must map to `Nil`, so the `cata lenAlg` didn't matter at all.

---

Let's look at the type of `Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil)`:

```
Nil                 :: ListF e a
Cons 2 Nil          :: ListF Int (ListF e a)
Cons 1 (Cons 2 Nil) :: ListF Int (ListF Int (ListF e a))
```

Something is awry here.  The trouble is that we are forgetting to do the opposite of `unFix` to roll the `ListF` back up into a regular list.  I will call this function

```
roll :: ListF e [e] -> [e]
```

Now we have

```
Nil                                      :: ListF e a
roll Nil                                 :: [e]
Cons 2 (roll Nil)                        :: ListF Int [Int]
roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil))                 :: [Int]
Cons 1 (roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))        :: ListF Int [Int]
roll (Cons 1 (roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))) :: [Int]
```

The types are staying nice and small now, it's a good sign.  For the execution trace, let's just note that `unFix . roll = id`, however they work. It's important here to notice that

```
fmap f (Cons a b) = Cons a (f b)
fmap f Nil        = Nil
```

That is, `fmap` on `ListF` just applies the function on the "recursive part" of the type.

I'm going to switch the `Cons` case to `lenAlg (ConsF e n) = 1 + n` to make the trace a tiny bit more readable.  Still kind of a mess, good luck.

```
cata lenAlg (roll (Cons 1 (roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))))
(lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) . unFix) (roll (Cons 1 (roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))))
lenAlg (fmap (cata lenAlg) (unFix (roll (Cons 1 (roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))))))
lenAlg (fmap (cata lenAlg) (Cons 1 (roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))))
lenAlg (Cons 1 (cata lenAlg (roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))))
1 + cata lenAlg (roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))
1 + (lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) . unFix) (roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))
1 + lenAlg (fmap (cata lenAlg) (unFix (roll (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))))
1 + lenAlg (fmap (cata lenAlg) (Cons 2 (roll Nil)))
1 + lenAlg (Cons 2 (cata lenAlg (roll Nil)))
1 + 1 + cata lenAlg (roll Nil)
1 + 1 + (lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) . unFix) (roll Nil)
1 + 1 + lenAlg (fmap (cata lenAlg) (unFix (roll Nil)))
1 + 1 + lenAlg (fmap (cata lenAlg Nil))
1 + 1 + lenAlg Nil
1 + 1 + 0
2
```

See also [my other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434292/catamorphism-and-tree-traversing-in-haskell) about catamorphisms.

Answer (score 4):

No, `unFix` exposes the structure, and then `fmap f` applies a function `f` on it. If it's a Leaf, `fmap f` will do its thing that it is defined to do for leaves - i.e., nothing. It's `fmap` that "knows" i.e. is defined to handle each case, as usual in Haskell's case-based  definitions.

```
Fix (ListF e) = ListF e (Fix (ListF e)) 
              = NilF | ConsF e (Fix (ListF e))
```

so renaming `Fix (ListF e)` to `Listof e` we get

```
Listof     e  = NilF | ConsF e (Listof e)
```

`Listof e` is a recursive type. **`ListF e r` is a non-recursive type.** `Fix` makes a recursive type out of it. `ListF e` being a Functor means `fmap` works on the `r` "meat", `ListF e` being the "hard outer shell" of this "fruit".

```
data ListF e a = NilF | ConsF e a

newtype Fix f = X { unFix    :: (f       (Fix f)) }

-- unFix ::    Fix f          -> f       (Fix f        )
-- unFix (_ :: Fix (ListF e)) :: ListF e (Fix (ListF e))

lenAlg :: ListF e Int -> Int
lenAlg (ConsF e n) = n + 1
lenAlg NilF        = 0

instance Functor (ListF e) where
    -- fmap :: (a -> b) -> (ListF e a) -> (ListF e b)
    fmap f NilF        = NilF
    fmap f (ConsF e r) = ConsF e (f r)

cata :: (ListF e Int -> Int) -> Fix (ListF e) -> Int
cata lenAlg x = (lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) . unFix) x
              =  lenAlg ( fmap (cata lenAlg) ( unFix  x ))
--------
        x       ::       Fix (ListF e)
        unFix x ::            ListF e (Fix (ListF e))
        fmap (cata lenAlg) :: ListF e (Fix (ListF e)) -> ListF e (Int)
              cata lenAlg  ::          Fix (ListF e)  ->          Int

        fmap (cata lenAlg)   (unFix  x              ) :: ListF e  Int 
 lenAlg (_                                            :: ListF e  Int ) :: Int
```

See? All the wires go to their proper places. `fmap` transforms the inner part `r` recursively, and then `lenAlg` *algebra* applies *one* last transformation, ***one*** last *step* in collapsing the structure where all its inner parts were already collapsed into a *r*ecursive *r*esult. Thus producing the final *r*esult.

---

As a concrete example, for a list of two numbers, *1* and *2*, we have

```
-- newtype Fix f  = X { unFix :: (f      (Fix f         )) }
--             _\_______       ____\____      _\________
onetwo :: Fix (ListF Int) -- ~ ListF Int (Fix (ListF Int))
onetwo = X (ConsF 1
                  (X (ConsF 2
                            (X NilF))))
```

```
cata lenAlg :: Fix (ListF e) -> Int
cata lenAlg    onetwo
  = {- definition of cata   -}
    lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) . unFix  $ onetwo
  = {- definition of onetwo -}
    lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) . unFix  $ 
                           X (ConsF 1 (X (ConsF 2 (X NilF))))
  = {- definition of unFix  -}
    lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) $ 
                              ConsF 1 (X (ConsF 2 (X NilF)))
  = {- definition of fmap   -}
    lenAlg $ ConsF 1 (cata lenAlg     (X (ConsF 2 (X NilF))))
  = {- definition of lenAlg -}
    (+ 1)  $          cata lenAlg     (X (ConsF 2 (X NilF)))
  = {- definition of cata   -}
    (+ 1)  $ lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) . unFix $ 
                                       X (ConsF 2 (X NilF))
  = {- definition of unFix  -}
    (+ 1) $ lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) $ ConsF 2 (X NilF)
  = {- definition of fmap   -}
    (+ 1) $ lenAlg $ ConsF 2 $ cata lenAlg        (X NilF)
  = {- definition of lenAlg -}
    (+ 1) $ (+ 1)  $           cata lenAlg        (X NilF)
  = {- definition of cata   -}
    (+ 1) $ (+ 1)  $ lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) . unFix $ 
                                                  (X NilF)
  = {- definition of unFix  -}
    (+ 1) $ (+ 1)  $ lenAlg . fmap (cata lenAlg) $   NilF
  = {- definition of fmap   -}
    (+ 1) $ (+ 1)  $ lenAlg $                        NilF
  = {- definition of lenAlg -}
    (+ 1) $ (+ 1)  $ 0
  = (+ 1) $ 1
  = 2
```

Also,

```
squaringAlg :: ListF Int [Int] -> [Int]
squaringAlg (ConsF e r) = e*e : r
squaringAlg NilF        = []

filteringAlg :: (e -> Bool) -> ListF e [e] -> [e]
filteringAlg p (ConsF e r) | p e       = e : r
                           | otherwise = r
filteringAlg _ NilF                    = []
```

etc.

Comment: Could you elaborate why Fix (ListF e) = ListF e (Fix (ListF e)) 
              = NilF | ConsF e (Fix (ListF e))? According to the definition newtype Fix f = Fix (f (Fix f)), shouldn't data constructor Fix be applied to ((ListF e) Fix (ListF e))?

Comment: I'm using `X` as the *data* constructor, to avoid the confusion. `Fix` is the *type* constructor. So, type `Fix (ListF e)` fits the definition `newtype Fix f = X (f (Fix f))` with the type parameter `f` becoming `(ListF e)`. So by substitution we get that the type `f (Fix f)` is `ListF e (Fix (ListF e))`. And `ListF` has two data constructors cases. That's what I meant by those two informal "equations".

Comment: or possibly you have some confusion about the parentheses?  `((f a) (b))` is just `f a b`. Similarly, `(f (Fix f))` with `f = (ListF e)` becomes  `((ListF e) (Fix (ListF e)))` and then, dropping superfluous parentheses, it is just `ListF e (Fix (ListF e))`.

Comment: I think I got it by reading your above comment *those two informal "equations"*. I just took the very first line of code literally and didn't feel Haskell compiler would compile. Now I see they are indicative pseudo code, rather than real code. Thanks!

Comment: the main block is all real code. and the derivation that you asked for uses it and follows its definitions specifically, step by step.

Comment: "[the accepted answer shows that] in order for Haskell compiler to figure out Functor A is a fixed point of Functor B, we need to be explicit" no, that answer tells you the opposite: compiler doesn't know anything. the "explicit" bit just means we must provide the missing Functor instance ourselves explicitly. A *mathematician* looking at those definitions concludes the type `Fix f` is a *type-level fixed-point* of the type `f`. A *Haskell implementation* just follows the definitions, as I showed in my answer. For it the type `Fix (ListF e)`, or `ListF e (Fix (ListF e))`, is just another type.

Comment: and "`Fix`" is just another type name. It could be named just "`T`" for all it cares. :) Same with the data constructors, that's why I used "`X`" there.